# How to connect to sharepoint on prem 2013 using CMIS

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, cmis

I want to get the SharePoint document library data using CMIS

Here is my code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                parameters[SessionParameter.BindingType] = BindingType.AtomPub;
                parameters[SessionParameter.AtomPubUrl] = "http://zeus:18439/_vti_bin/cmis/rest/CD4E6A20-32DD-46F5-96A8-00EF7B754EC2?getRepositoryInfo";
                parameters[SessionParameter.User] = strSourceUserName;
                parameters[SessionParameter.Password] = strSourcePassword;
                SessionFactory factory = SessionFactory.NewInstance();
                migrateRepos = factory.GetRepositories(parameters);
```

I am getting an `Unauthorized exception` at `GetRepositories()` method. The stack trace is

```
at DotCMIS.Binding.AtomPub.AbstractAtomPubService.Read(UrlBuilder url)
   at DotCMIS.Binding.AtomPub.AbstractAtomPubService.GetRepositoriesInternal(String repositoryId)
   at DotCMIS.Binding.AtomPub.RepositoryService.GetRepositoryInfos(IExtensionsData extension)
   at DotCMIS.Binding.Impl.BindingRepositoryService.GetRepositoryInfos(IExtensionsData extension)
   at DotCMIS.Client.Impl.SessionFactory.GetRepositories(IDictionary`2 parameters, IObjectFactory objectFactory, AbstractAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider, ICache cache)
   at DotCMIS.Client.Impl.SessionFactory.GetRepositories(IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at ReadFileInfo.AlfrescoAnalysis.MigrateCMISData() in D:\TFS\Optimum - MigrationTools\Alfresco_Analysis\ReadFileInfo\AlfrescoAnalysis.cs:line 289
```

Glad for any help..Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be aware of using CMIS requires enabling **Basic
Authentication** for your web application to avoid `Unauthorized exception`.

> For more details, check **[CMIS Prerequisites In SharePoint 2016](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sharepoint-2016-configure-cmis/#configure-cmis-in-sharepoint-2016-prerequisites)**

---

**Solution**

You should Enable **Basic Authentication** to your Web Application at `Claims Authentication Types`  by doing the following:

- Open Central Administration > Application Management > Manage web application.
- Click on your web application, from the above ribbon, select `Authentication Provider`.
- Check `Basic authentication (credentials are sent in clear text)`

> For more details, check **[Configure CMIS In SharePoint 2016](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sharepoint-2016-configure-cmis/)**

Comment: Check more details at **[SharePoint 2016: Configure Content Management Interoperability Services (CMIS)](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sharepoint-2016-configure-cmis/)**